# Why are block settings lost after Drupal upgrade?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, upgrade, drupal-blocks

This is a new one for me.  I upgraded a Drupal site from 6.20 to 6.22.  After the core upgrade, the block visibility settings are all goofed up.  Quite a few that were enabled prior to the upgrade are now disabled.  Additionally, the "Page specific visibility settings" are missing for those blocks.

One other clue in this mystery is that, on the main block admin page (/admin/build/block), my three active themes are in a different order.  I'm not sure whether that's related, but I've never seen it before.

I do upgrades on a staging server, so my production site is still intact.  For now, I'm going to restore the blocks, comparing the prod with staging settings.  I'll see if that restores it to fully functional.  Regardless, it makes me nervous.  I saw no errors or warning during upgrade.

FYI, my general order for doing the upgrade was:

1. Empty staging site files and dbase.
2. Take production site offline.
3. Copy entire prod site to staging.
4. Dump prod dbase, restore to staging dbase.
5. Disable all non-core modules. Switch to core theme (Garland).
6. Upload and expand drupal-6.22.
7. Move 'sites' directory from old to new.
8. Run /update.php.
9. Enable necessary non-core modules.
10. Run /update.php.
11. Switch back to custom theme.

Bam, lots of blocks disabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. See http://drupal.org/node/1173012

Comment: As of right now, Carlos is requesting a DB dump of an affected site in the linked issue queue. If you're here, wishing someone over there could help fix your site, you should talk to Carlos (and ask him if he still needs a copy of the DB). Please review comments from http://drupal.org/node/1173012#comment-4551670 onwards to see if this comment of mine is still relevant.